# http: Accept error: accept tcp [::]:8080: accept4: too many open files;

Tags: linux, go

I have written REST API in Golang and I am doing performance test of my API using Jmeter. 
When I run the test with 300 or more users, each user sending 20 requests with a gap of 500ms between each request I get the below error:

> http: Accept error: accept tcp [::]:8080: accept4: too many open files;

I am running this Go application in AWS EC2 server. I am running this app on a 8GB RAM machine. 
Below is what I have tried already:

1. I have increased the ulimit to a sufficiently good number. When I run ulimit -n command the output is: 1048576
2. In my code I made sure that the response body is closed.

But, none of these solved the issue. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One problem could be not closing the opened files or releasing the resources. 
For example: the body object in http request is of type io.ReadCloser
This read closer has a close method which you must call after your process has been finished to release the resources.

```
func UserHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.request) {
    var user User

    if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&user); err != nil {
      //handle error
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()

  // More Code
}
```

Here calling a **defer** on the ***r.Body.Close()*** will lead to releasing the associated resources after the method has returned its value.

Similar To this, there are alot of methods which implement this interface, like: *** os.File, sql.DB, mgo.Session*** etc. So you can just check if you're properly closing the resources.